# Is it possible to access moved internal elements of a stack?

Tags: c++, stl, copy, move

I looked up https://cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/push/ and it says

> `void push (const value_type& val);`
> Insert element
> Inserts a new element at the top of the stack, above its current top element. The content of this new element is initialized to a copy of val.

This member function effectively calls the member function push_back of the underlying container object.

I am not aware of the internals of `stack` `push` but I am wondering if it is possible to move elements into a stack to avoid unnecessary copy.

Something like this does not work:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack<int> myStack;

    int a0 = 0;
    int *a0p = &a0;
    int a1 = 10;
    int *a1p = &a1;
    int a2 = 20;
    int *a2p = &a2;

    // myStack.push(a0);
    // myStack.push(a1);
    // myStack.push(a2);
    myStack.push(move(a0));
    myStack.push(move(a1));
    myStack.push(move(a2));

    *a1p = 7;
    cout<<"a1 changed via the pointer is "<<a1<<endl;

    while(!myStack.empty()) {
        cout<<myStack.top()<<endl;
        myStack.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As it gives the output:

```
a1 changed via the pointer is 7
20
10
0
```

How is the present behavior enforced?

**EDIT:**

From the suggestion to use a class with `move` assignment instead of int.

I am getting segmentation fault on the below code.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack<vector<int>> myStack;


    vector<int> a0 = {0,1,2};
    auto *a0p = &a0;
    vector<int> a1 = {10,11,12};
    auto *a1p = &a1;
    vector<int> a2 = {20,21,22};
    auto *a2p = &a2;


    // myStack.push(a0);
    // myStack.push(a1);
    // myStack.push(a2);
    // myStack.emplace(a0);
    // myStack.emplace(a1);
    // myStack.emplace(a2);
    myStack.push(move(a0));
    myStack.push(move(a1));
    myStack.push(move(a2));


    (*a1p)[1] = 7; // Getting segmentation fault here
    cout<<"a1[1] changed via the pointer is "<<a1[1]<<endl;


    while(!myStack.empty()) {
        cout<<myStack.top()[0]<<" "<<myStack.top()[1]<<" "<<myStack.top()[2]<<endl;
        myStack.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, using

```
myStack.push(a1);
myStack.emplace(a1);
```

Both give the same output

```
a1[1] changed via the pointer is 7
20 21 22
10 11 12
0 1 2
```

BTW, my c++ version is 201703, g++ is 8.1.0.

I have clarified the title and want to ask again, why cannot I access internal elements of a stack? How is this behavior enforced?

Comment: Don't use that website as your reference. Use https://cppreference.com, which is actively maintained. See [std::stack::push](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/push). Note that `std::move` for raw pointers and `int` values is kinda useless.

Comment: The whole idea of std::move is that you move moveable objects so you can get rid of pointers

Comment: `std::move` doesn't move anything. It just says treat the value as an expiring r-value. Like when a regular value (not a reference) is returned from a function. It's not an l-value. Moving ints, pointers, etc doesn't do anything. It only has effects on classes with move assignments/ctors

Comment: And if you're going to move then use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack/emplace

Comment: Read Howard Hinnant's excellent piece on [std::move](https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf)

Comment: Also, copying an `int` means "take 4 bytes from here, and store them there". It doesn't get any cheaper than that!

Comment: What did you expect `(*a1p)[1]` to do after you moved the vector? After a move the vector is in an unspecified state, which also means all references and iterators to it are invalidated. The segfault only shows that the move worked. If you want a reference to the vector on the stack you have to take it from the stack and not before the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried as suggested by @Goswin von Brederlow to take reference to the vector from the stack and not before the move and I am now able to change the contents of the internal elements of a stack.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    stack<vector<int>> myStack;


    vector<int> a0 = {0,1,2};
    auto *a0p = &a0;
    vector<int> a1 = {10,11,12};
    auto *a1p = &a1;
    vector<int> a2 = {20,21,22};
    auto *a2p = &a2;


    // myStack.push(a0);
    // myStack.push(a1);
    // myStack.push(a2);
    // myStack.emplace(a0);
    // myStack.emplace(a1);
    // myStack.emplace(a2);
    myStack.push(move(a0));
    myStack.push(move(a1));
    auto *a1p2 = &myStack.top();
    myStack.push(move(a2));


    // (*a1p)[1] = 7; // Getting segmentation fault here
    (*a1p2)[1] = 7;

    while(!myStack.empty()) {
        cout<<myStack.top()[0]<<" "<<myStack.top()[1]<<" "<<myStack.top()[2]<<endl;
        myStack.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20 21 22
10 7 12
0 1 2
```

Here are the contents of the variables. I am however still unable to understand why a vector's address changes after a move. Why are a1p and a1p2 different?

[image]

As per @Goswin von Brederlow,

"After a move the vector is in an unspecified state, which also means all references and iterators to it are invalidated."

wouldn't this be expensive?

Comment: I see now how a vector's address changes after a move. It's not the underlying array whose address changes but the wrapping vector structure. It's in slide 6 of https://accu.org/conf-docs/PDFs_2014/Howard_Hinnant_Accu_2014.pdf.